# создать HashMap<Integer, String> из ArrayList<String>,

Tags: строки, arraylist, index, hashmap, int

подскажите пожалуйста,
как создать  HashMap<Integer, String> из ArrayList.
ключом HashMap<Integer, String> будет индекс ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Циклом:

```
public class Test7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add("Hello");
      list.add("world");
      list.add("java");
      Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>();
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
          map.put(i,list.get(i));
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

выход:

```
{0=Hello, 1=world, 2=java}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое